# Adding a PATCH method to Backbone collections

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I have a web application that is using a Django/Tastypie backend with a Backbone/Marionette frontend.  I'd like to use Tastypie's [bulk operations](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#bulk-operations) to create multiple objects via my API using a PATCH request to a list endpoint.

My understanding is that Backbone doesn't support this.  What is the best way to add this to Backbone?  I assume I'll need to add a save method to Backbone's collection object and extend the Backbone sync method.

Answer (score 4):

From http://backbonejs.org/

```
   If instead, you'd only like the changed attributes to be sent to the server, call 
   model.save(attrs, {patch: true}). You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server
   with just the passed-in attributes.
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/r9kXL/10/) Sending patch request on backbone collection sync:

```
$(function() {

  Backbone.$ = $;

  var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/testUrl",
    isNew : function () { return false; },
    defaults: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 25
    }
  });
  var user1 = new User();
  var user2 = new User();
  var user3 = new User();
  var user4 = new User();
  var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    url: "/testUrl"
  });
  var userCollection = new UserCollection([ user1, user2, user3]);
  // update
  user1.set('name','Jane Doe');
  user4.set('name','Another User');

  // delete
  userCollection.remove(user2);

  // add
  userCollection.add(user4);

  userCollection.sync('patch', userCollection , { error: function () {                       
    console.log(userCollection); } });
  });
```

Comment: I'm talking about collections -- not models.  Backbone collections don't have a save method out of the box.

Comment: I was not fully aware of the options available via Backbone.sync's arguments.  I like it!  I will give that a shot and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: I still need to change the Backbone.sync object to conform to the Tastypie expectations for a PATCH request to a list endpoint.  Specifically, the expectations provided here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#bulk-operations

Comment: @Erik seems so after reading your link. I got more focused on backbone side. I am not sure but https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie may come useful.

Comment: I ended up using a custom Backbone.ajax request to the list endpoint to send the PATCH request in a format acceptable to Tastypie.  Putting a collection.fetch() in the success hash of the ajax call seems to get me on my way.  Thanks for your help!